# char* in struct memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct, char

So I have a struct like this (in fact it's bigger):

```
struct _setup {
    char* selfName;
    int8_t zone;
    char* selfSSID;
    char* selfWPA2;
}
```

I'm using it to hold config for my device; JSON was an idea but it's taking much resources and time to proces.
I want to allocate 32 chars for each char*.
What will be happening to this struct:
1. Filled with data of unknown length BUT shorter than 32 bytes
2. Saved to EEPROM
3. Read from EEPROM to another struct (same layout)

I've tried malloc and new inside the struct but it didn't work.
What is the correct way to allocate memory and write data to struct?

Comment: Why not `char varName[32]`?

Comment: Because when I'm reading struct on another machine I don't want to convert char[] again to char*

Comment: @FotelPL You won't have to convert it the array to a pointer, since both can be used in place of each other (Because of char arrays/pointers being defined similarly and because of decay).

Comment: _I've tried malloc and new inside the struct but it didn't work._ What exactly didn't work?

Comment: @MichaelWalz `char* selfName = (char*)malloc(32*sizeof(char))`  Same thing with 'new'.

Comment: @FotelPL yes, but _how_ did it not work? Did it erase your hard drive? Did it set your house on fire?

Comment: It didn't allocate space in the manner I wanted it to; because *maybe somewhere* it was allocated but after writing the struct to file, size of the file was smaller than amount of data I wanted to write.

Comment: How did you write it? If you used a method that expects a null terminated string, it would stop when encountering `\0` whereas you might expect it to write the full 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two option for allocating memory for struct members:

1-  Static memory allocation:

```
struct _setup {
    char selfName[32];
    int8_t zone;
    char selfSSID[32];
    char selfWPA2[32];
}
```

Static allocation recommended if your allocation size is short and you know that size at compile time. otherwise use dynamic allocation.

static allocation is faster than dynamic allocation. but if you want to create huge count of object from this struct you may get Stackoverflow exception. becasue you may utilize all stack space. (if your real array size is about 32, Stackoverflow exception is improbable)

2- Dynamic Allocation :

```
struct _setup {
    char* selfName;
    int8_t zone;
    char* selfSSID;
    char* selfWPA2;
    _setup()
    {
         selfName= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
         selfSSID= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
         selfWPA2= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
    }
    ~_setup()
    {
         free(selfName);
         free(selfSSID);
         free(selfWPA2);
    }
}
```

you can use Dynamic allocation with malloc or new operators. but you should remember that you must **free()** these dynamic memories after using them. I placed free in distructor, you can put those everywhere you want.

Comment: Why no `~_setup()` to free them?

Comment: @patatahooligan you are completely right. Freeing in destructor is good idea

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally use `std::string` and not `char*` if in `c++`

For your code, this could be more readable way along with destructor:

```
struct _setup {
    char* selfName;
    int8_t zone;
    char* selfSSID;
    char* selfWPA2;
    _setup()
    {
         selfName = new char[32];
         selfSSID = new char[32];
         selfWPA2 = new char[32]; //Or this for direct value: new char [strlen("hello") + 1];
        //strcpy(selfWPA2, "hello");
    }

    ~_setup()
    {
        delete selfName;
        delete selfSSID;
        delete selfWPA2;

    }
};
```